# Manipulate gets stuck when ConvexHullMesh is made transparent

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate, graphics3d, mesh

Version 10.3

The followinng `Manipulate` is a bit slow, but quite OK

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
   ConvexHullMesh[ Tuples[Range[10], 3]], 
   Graphics3D[
     Parallelepiped[{-5, 0, -zero}, {a {1, 0, 0}, b {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, c}}]], 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000}], {zero, 20, 0}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 
  10}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

But if I rotate the points two times as follows, it is much slower,

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ConvexHullMesh[
   RotationTransform[{{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {0, 0, 0}]@
    RotationTransform[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, {0, 0, 0}]@
     Tuples[Range[10], 3]], 
  Graphics3D[
   Parallelepiped[{-5, 0, -zero}, {a {1, 0, 0}, 
     b {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, c}}]], 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000}], {zero, 20, 0}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 
  10}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

What is more, if I add some `Opacity` to the mesh, `Manipulate` is in a complete paralysis

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ConvexHullMesh[
   RotationTransform[{{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {0, 0, 0}]@
    RotationTransform[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, {0, 0, 0}]@
     Tuples[Range[10], 3], MeshCellHighlight -> Opacity[0.5]], 
  Graphics3D[
   Parallelepiped[{-5, 0, -zero}, {a {1, 0, 0}, 
     b {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, c}}]], 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000}], {zero, 20, 0}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 
  10}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: If you don't want to manipulate the convex hull you can simply compute it outsite of `Manipulate` and plug the result into `Show`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Opacity` always gives a huge performance drop in interacting with `Graphics3D`.

So let's skip it during interactions with `Sliders` using `ControlActive`.

And of course the main thing, as noted in comments, do not calculate the same mesh each time:

```
mesh = ConvexHullMesh[
   RotationTransform[{{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {0, 0, 0}]@
    RotationTransform[{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, {0, 0, 0}]@
     Tuples[Range[10], 3]];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  HighlightMesh[mesh, ControlActive[{}, Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]]],
  Graphics3D[
   Parallelepiped[{-5, 0, -zero},
    {a {1, 0, 0}, b {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, {0, 0, c}}]],
  ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 1000.}],
 {zero, 20, 0}, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Yep, the second bullet point in the Graphics section [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#843702347) says why. `"For graphics scenes that include no transparency, a hardware-accelerated depth buffer is used. Otherwise, the renderer uses a binary space partition tree to split and sort polygons from any viewpoint. The BSP tree is slower to create and is not hardware accelerated, but it provides the most general ability to support polygons."`

Comment: Thank you, but when draging the slider, the cube is not transparent. Could it be improved?

Comment: @ChipHurst Thank you for providing this useful page

Comment: @matheorem Have you read my answer? :) You don't have to use `ControlActive` if you don't want to.

Comment: Oh, why you add `ControlActive`? A bit misleading : )   Works well with `HighlightMesh[mesh,  Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]]` with `ControlActive`

Comment: @matheorem just in case someone would like to give some more features for a spped up :)

Comment: Oh, my post put on hold as off-topic again. So frustrating :(  I really can't see that it is simple or easily found in the documentation.